# Animate PickerView Height Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting to animate a `UIDatePicker` as I would animate a `UIView`, by changing the `height` constraint constant and animating it. But in `UIDatePicker` this doesn't work, everything around it animates, but the height instantly changes.

```
private func increasePicker() {

    pickerHeight.constant = 200
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

What's is the right way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Showing some code nd/or things you tried already can help entice answers.

Comment: Throw some code in your question to show what you've tried. As @swa66 said, you'll get better answers with a more specific question.

Comment: @Adrian will do! Will get to my computer and put some code here! Thanks!

Comment: @swa66 edited with some code, thanks for the tip

Comment: Height change of date picker is not really animatable; it's too complex internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
private func increasePicker()
{
 pickerHeight.constant = 200
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
}
```